# how to have hash of list in perl

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

Sorry for this syntax question. I fail to find the solution.
I want to have an array of hashs in perl, each of them has string and array.
I'm trying to write the following code:

```
use strict;
my @arr = (
       { name => "aaa" , values => ("a1","a2") },
       { name => "bbb" , values => ("b1","b2","b3") }
      );


foreach $a (@arr) {
  my @cur_values = @{$a->{values}};
  print("values of $a->{name} = @cur_values\n");
};
```

But this does not work for me. I get compilation error and warning (using perl -w)

Odd number of elements in anonymous hash at a.pl line 2.
Can't use string ("a1") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at a.pl line 9.

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html is a great reference for this type of thing.

Comment: try to avoid using `$a` (and `$b`) as variable names - these are special cases reserved for `sort`...

Comment: You should always enable warnings when developing Perl code. It would have pointed out where there is a problem...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following:

```
use strict;
my @arr = (
       { name => "aaa" , values => ["a1","a2"] },
       { name => "bbb" , values => ["b1","b2","b3"] }
      );


foreach $a (@arr) {
  my @cur_values = @{$a->{values}};
  print("values of $a->{name}: ");
    foreach $b (@cur_values){
        print $b . ", "
    }
    print "\n";
};
```

You just needed to use square brackets when defining your array on lines 3 and 4.

Comment: You should really use a lexical loop variable (and not use `$a`, which has magical properties.)

Answer (score 8):

> I want to have an array of hashs in perl

You can't. Arrays only contain scalars in Perl. However, `{}` will create a hashref, which is a scalar and is fine.

But this:

```
{ name => "aaa" , values => ("a1","a2") }
```

means the same as:

```
{ name => "aaa" , values => "a1", "a2" },
```

You want an arrayref (which is a scalar), not a list for the value.

```
{ name => "aaa" , values => ["a1","a2"] }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
my @arr = (
            { name => "aaa" , values => ["a1","a2"]      },
            { name => "bbb" , values => ["b1","b2","b3"] }
          );
```

Lists ( made with `()`) will get flattened. Arrayrefs (`[]`) won't.

See [`perldoc perlreftut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) for more.

Also, avoid using `$a` and `$b` as variable names as they are intended for special use inside `sort` blocks.